# Using WebMatrix and Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using WebMatrix to edit my web page. After clicking on the Run button, I can see the time being displayed, but when launching the page from the desktop I see the source code [@m_date.ToString()].
--snip--

```
@{var m_date = DateTime.Now; }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 ....
</head>
<body>
...
    <p style="text-align: center">@m_date.ToString()</p>
...
</body
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is "launching the page from the desktop"?

Answer (score 0):

Razor is a server-side technology. This means that your page needs to be processed by a server. This server turns the mix of html and razor code, into plain Html. This Html can then be rendered by your browser.

When you open a .cshtml directly in your browser, the razor code is not processed, and is displayed as the contents.

Comment: So, for someone to see my Razor or ASP.NET page they have to have use WebMatrix or Microsoft Visual studio for Web?
This is not good, why not use XHTML or HTML5 if only people with access to my server will see my page?
If programming for the internet is like this, why not just hand out CDs with your program.

Comment: You are supposed to host your website on a webserver. For example Windows Azure (this is **free** for small sites). This way you can execute logic on your server. Like queurying and updating your database. Compare this to burning Facebook on a CD and being send to everybody as soon as someone changes his/her status.

Comment: I got to check this Azure thing, it is nice of Microsoft to offer a server to test their web products.
Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

Webmatrix uses a server ([IIS express](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview) most probably in your case) to launch your page. When you hit run it starts your browser and you go to url like `localhost:12345` with the rendered (already processed) page.

If you have saved this page to your desktop it will be either html or cshtml depending on how you saved it. Then clicking on it does not process it, but rather you ask the browser to show the contents.

Here is an [intro to Webmatrix](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/06/introducing-webmatrix.aspx) to understand how it works and what it does when you do trivial things like this one.